# startx doesn't work

Tags: xorg, login

Let's see, I cannot log in in Lubuntu 12.04.  On the shell I get when typing startx:

```
  _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener()  failed
  _XSERVTransMakeA11C0TSServerListeners: server already running

  Fatal server error:
  Cannot establich any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running

 ...
 Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.  
 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
 Server terminated with error (1). CLosing log file

 Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
 xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
 xinit: server error
```

Before I had only read-right on the file-system with sudo autoremove I got my write-rights back.  I removed the .Xauthority* files in /home/username. Still cannot login back

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution for me: Well, I hope someone can use my answer:

I changed my password, reinstalled xserver-xorg by typing:   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg`

After a reboot it worked for me. Notice: I removed the .XAuthority files in /home/username by: `sudo rm /home/username/.XAuthority*`

to get a shell try Strg-Alt-F1 when you turn on your computer. I actually got my write-rights back by using `clear` in recovery mode.

Hopefully, this answer can help others as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I'd spent the last hour removing Xauthority files and getting rid of xinitrc and reinstalling xorg and rebooting, but somehow doing it in this sequence worked.

Comment: Had a freeze after entering password on login screen, while being able to enter via ssh. Removing .Xauthority files worked.

Answer (score 4):

I got this message too, in my case the X server was indeed already running, I just had to switch to terminal 7 (the first GUI terminal) by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after 2 hours of search I ended up with x.org FAQ messages page, in that page explained to deal with these two errors like each others:
1 - `"Server is already active for display 0"`
2 - `"Cannot establish any listening sockets..."`
 It seems that X server is running, but you cannot just type startx -- :1 and start a new one, you should remove these two files:

```
/home/username/.XAuthority*

/opt/.X0-lock
```

and then start new X server on another display:

```
startx --:1
```

and then done! my screen back!
I just tried to help here,
for more information, this is the link that I found on www.x.org
http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/#index5h2

Answer (score -1):

Did you "Make sure an X server isn't already running" by trying something like `startx -- :1`? Maybe a [g|x|light]dm process was already running and blocking DISPLAY :0.

Comment: I cannot tell you really whether that was a problem...  Now everything is fine..  I put the solution in the edit, because I couldn't have answered it myself, since I'm a newbie in the forum.

Answer (score -2):

I get similar message to run

```
Xorg -configure
```

You test free space disk:

```
df -Th
```

For my case was this and if it has 100% You can get free space disk width

```
apt-get clean
```

Comment: It isn't very clear how this is an answer. Could you clarify that bit? Thanks.