# Ubuntu not allowing me to log in after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, login-screen

I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 and it went fine. After restart, when I try to log in from my root user it shows a command screen in a split second and then returns back to the log in screen which shows all users. I have even tried to test logging in with other users and it is working fine.

I guess there is some problem with home folder of my user or something. Kindly help me out otherwise my only hope is to make a fresh install from a CD which I am avoiding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `root` user, do you mean the following account: `root@your-hostname`? Or an account that is part of `sudoers` (i.e., accounts that can't execute `sudo`)?

Answer (score -1):

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/185236/22949) originally [by actionparsnip](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/197479) worked for me:

```
Press CTRL+ALT+F1

Log in with you user name and password

Run the following command: sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME

Press CTRL+ALT+F7
Try to log in
```

Comment: Recursively changing file user/group ownership should be done with very much care. Please don't suggest this out of nowhere.

Comment: why don't you also tell what are the consequences of doing this? And give the solution to this problem instead of preaching.

Comment: The answer is correct.  It can be made clear --only /home/<user>/.Xauthority files needs to be chowned.